# Installing a private package from Gitlab with Yarn

Tags: gitlab, yarnpkg, npm-package, npm-private-modules

I have a private npm package that is published to the Gitlab Package Registry using a Gitlab CI pipeline.

I want to install this package in a project using **yarn**.

Following the documentation helped me come up with the following `.npmrc` file :

```
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=glpat-***********
@my-org:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
```

With the above, `npm install @my-org/my-package` works perfectly.
However, `yarn add @my-org/my-package` fails. using `--verbose` shows a 404 :

```
verbose 1.169823875 Error: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<my-project-id>/packages/npm/@my-org/my-package/-/@my-org/my-package-1.0.3.tgz: Request failed "404 Not Found"


error An unexpected error occurred: "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<my-project-id>/packages/npm/@my-org/my-package/-/@my-org/my-package-1.0.3.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\""
```

The package does exist at version 1.0.3, NPM installs it.

- I need to get this to work with Yarn. How can I do this ?
- Additionaly, is there a way to take the authToken out of the `.npmrc` file ?

Answer (score 1):

Your config in `.npmrc` should work if you are using Yarn v1.x, as Yarn 1 uses the registries configured in this file.

However, for Yarn 2, you must configure your private registries in the `.yarnc.yml` at the project level:

```yaml
npmScopes:
  my-org:
    npmRegistryServer: "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/my-project-id/packages/npm/"
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: glpat-*******
```

Replace `my-org` with the scope of your package, my-project-id with the numeric id of your Gitlab project, and put your token with scope "api".

Answer (score 0):

I also was not able to install it with yarn, but npm was ok.

This this worked out:

```
npm config set -- //gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=XXX

npm config set -- //gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectID>/packages/npm/:_authToken=XXX

npm config set @my-scope:registry https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/  

yarn config set '//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:_authToken' "XXX"

yarn config set '//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken' "XXX"
```

And no need for .npmrc for this setup.

Here is the official GitLab [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/yarn_repository/#error-running-yarn-with-the-package-registry-for-the-npm-registry) on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things, including all mentioned in this post, but none worked.
Now, I do not know why, but the following worked for me:

Anonymized:

```
@XXXXX:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:_authToken=XXXXX
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=XXXXX
```

Abstracted:

```
@<my-org>:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//<gitlab-url>/api/v4/projects/:_authToken=<auth-token>
//<gitlab-url>/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=<auth-token>
```

My auth token is in my main gitlab group and holds only the right to `read package repository`.
Both packages are in different groups below that one.

Following the docs you get urls with `project/<id>/npm` and `packages/npm` but the key I think is adding the middle line that isn't really documented.